# not getting proper string in assign function in c++ when trying to get data from file

Tags: c++, string, assign

```
data.assign( content,
             (content.find_first_of("= ")) + 3, 
             content.find_first_of('\n')-content.find_first_of("= ") + 3);
```

I am getting invalid length of string when reading from file and comparing it with local string in my code what checking I have missed in this it can be '\0' or '\n' at the end of the file means I am trying to get the data from file from '=' character I find to end of that line file could be of one line or multiple line I just need data upto '\n' or '\0'

content : Scenario = sampl_verification

data : sampl_verification

data size : 19
data length : 19
cdata : sampl_verification
cdata size : 18
cdata length : 18

Comment: The issue with `\n` shouldn't be one if you read `string`s with [`std::getline()`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::getline` instead of `std::assign`. [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) reads data upto '\n' or '\0'.

For more info, you can read these -

[std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

[std::assign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign)